# Rebuild RHEL source package (SRPM) for Libreoffice -- are the build dependencies not packaged?

Tags: rpm, rhel, libreoffice, rebuild

I have a system running RHEL 8.1.  This includes a packaged version of LibreOffice:

```
% rpm -qi libreoffice-base
Name        : libreoffice-base
Epoch       : 1
Version     : 6.0.6.1
Release     : 19.el8
Architecture: x86_64
Install Date: Fri 21 Feb 2020 05:16:08 PM GMT
Group       : Unspecified
Size        : 7511388
License     : (MPLv1.1 or LGPLv3+) and LGPLv3 and LGPLv2+ and BSD and (MPLv1.1 or GPLv2 or LGPLv2 or Netscape) and Public Domain and ASL 2.0 and MPLv2.0 and CC0
Signature   : RSA/SHA256, Tue 20 Aug 2019 02:38:29 PM BST, Key ID 199e2f91fd431d51
Source RPM  : libreoffice-6.0.6.1-19.el8.src.rpm
[etc]
```

I'd like to rebuild this RPM package from its source package.  So I went to Red Hat's download page
https://access.redhat.com/downloads/content/libreoffice-base/6.0.6.1-19.el8/x86_64/fd431d51/package which unfortunately requires a login to access, and downloaded the source package `libreoffice-6.0.6.1-19.el8.src.rpm`.  Then I installed the source package with `rpm -Uvh` as usual and it created files under the `SPECS` and `SOURCES` directories in my RPM build directory.

Then as usual I went to build it:

```
% cd SPECS
% rpmbuild -ba libreoffice.spec
error: Failed build dependencies:
        bsh is needed by libreoffice-1:6.0.6.1-19.el8.x86_64
        glm-devel is needed by libreoffice-1:6.0.6.1-19.el8.x86_64
        gpgmepp-devel is needed by libreoffice-1:6.0.6.1-19.el8.x86_64
        [etc]
```

Not too surprising, I hadn't expected all of the build dependencies to be already present.  So I went to install them, starting with `bsh`:

```
% sudo dnf -y install bsh
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 0:39:20 ago on Fri 28 Feb 2020 09:39:22 AM GMT.
No match for argument: bsh
Error: Unable to find a match: bsh
```

Now I'm a bit stumped.  The package `bsh` is required to build `libreoffice-base`, which is a core package, yet `bsh` is not packaged?  I hope there's something obvious I am missing here.  The alternative would be that RHEL isn't self-hosting, which would be very depressing.

Answer (score 2):

Enable EPEL repository and then just:

```
dnf install mock
mock -r epel-8-x86_64 libreoffice-6.0.6.1-19.el8.src.rpm
```

wait few hours and then you are done.

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing that.  Interestingly mock does not install bsh inside the chroot, although `rpmbuild -ba` thought that bsh was a build dependency.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guarantee that those dependencies are available in the official repositories. You have to search for them. In this case I found `bsh` in the **centos7-os** repository. I suppose you should find them in your **redhat7-os** repository. Are you sure you have all your repositories enabled? (Watch out for license problems on redhat).

edit: you can find it for example here: http://ftp.riken.jp/Linux/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/bsh-1.3.0-29.el7.noarch.rpm

Comment: Yes, it's there in older RHEL versions but I don't see it packaged for RHEL 8.  I would like to check CentOS 8 but I couldn't see where to download the source packages (SRPMs) -- do you have a link?

Comment: you can just browse the directory from the url I have given you... or try searching yourself here: http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3

I didn't find bsh on centos8 (yet). not all packages are available already on centos8 I think.

Comment: Sorry I did look for CentOS 8.1 source packages on that ftp site, but I didn't find them.  Do you know where they might be?  I think the rpm.pbone.net doesn't have CentOS source packages, for example searching for 'centos-release' finds binary RPMs but no SRPMs.